# Bootstrap DateTimePicker Start Time

Tags: date, twitter-bootstrap, time, datetimepicker

I'm using two DateTimePickers  http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ in my code: one for choosing a date (pickTime disabled) and the other for the time (pickDate disabled).

I've managed to set a startDate for the date, but how can I set a startTime and an endTime, in such a way that the any time before that startTime is disabled?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false,
      startDate: new Date(2013,9,8)
    });
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
      pickDate: false,
      startTime: ???
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This may help you http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I've seen that before but I can't find the solution to my problem. Anyone have an idea??

Answer (score 0):

This question is OLD but thought it might help some one.

JS

```js
$('.time').datetimepicker({
      format: 'LT'
  }).on("dp.change",function(e){
      var date = e.date;//e.date is a moment object
      var target = $(e.target).attr('name');
      console.log(date.format("HH:mm:ss"))//get time by using format
  })
```

e.date is a moment object thus time can derived by using format("HH:mm:ss")